# imap_open(): Couldn't open stream on linux server

Tags: php, linux, xampp, imap

My code is working fine when run on windows laptop with XAMPP, but when I try to run same code on linux machine it is giving error.
My code:

```
<?php
$connect_to = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$user = 'my gmail address';
$password = 'my gmail password';

$connection = imap_open($connect_to, $user, $password)
  or die("Can't connect to '$connect_to': " . imap_last_error());

imap_close($connection);
?>
```

Error I am getting:

```
PHP Warning:imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX in /home/re-work/test_imap.php on line 30
Array
(
    [type] => 2
    [message] => imap_open(): Couldn't open stream {imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX
    [file] => /home/re-work/test_imap.php
    [line] => 30
)
PHP Warning:  imap_num_msg() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/re-work/test_imap.php on line 39
PHP Warning:  imap_search() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/re-work/test_imap.php on line 42
0</br>PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Retrying PLAIN authentication after [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco (errflg=1) in Unknown on line 0
PHP Notice:  Unknown: Can not authenticate to IMAP server: [ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco (errflg=2) in Unknown on line 0
```

Please help where and what I am missing?

Comment: imap is installed on server. What could be the possible configuration or part which I would have to check.Any suggestion please

Comment: Have you checked for firewall settings?

Comment: what should be the ideal firewall setting to run this as we are in deployment phase so therev is no firewall setting which in anyways restricting it...

Comment: this works fine on laptop in windows environment XAMPP, but as we run it over linux server it does not execute. Please help us with some suggestion.

Comment: i guess this issue is not having solution..

Comment: Are you sure port 993 is open on your server?  It isn't in many hosted environments.

Comment: Yes port 993 is open...telnet imap.gmail.com 993 successful

Comment: Google has blocked you for coming from a weird IP.  Implement OAuth, or log in from a web browser from wherever you're hosting it.

Comment: Max, I have tried same code from 7-8 servers with different geolocations  via aws instance. Same code runs fine when I run from my laptop XAMPP. Will try to implement OAuth and retry.

Comment: Users don't generally run their email browsers on aws, so that looks like a security breach to google.

Comment: Max I mean to say that the code which is in concern is working fine on windows browser... But when it is executed on linux machine its not working and failing at 1st step of logging in using IMAP.

Comment: Yes, has your linux machine ever logged into the gmail website?  Is it a place users normally log in from?  Presumably not, so Google thinks it's an 'unusual' login.  This error is from the Gmail server when it detects an unusual login: `[ALERT] Please log in via your web browser: https://support.google.com/mail/acco...`

Comment: Ok I got your point bro, my requirement is that I have to parse content of my test email ids and want to perform few actions based on content. I thought to run a program on server and could proceed to do what I am looking for. But probably gmail on identifying the OS as linux not the browser it is stopping from logging in. I would request you to have a look on Return-Path inbox monitor tool then how that works, if you could provide your understanding on same would be great for us.

Comment: If your account is set up for it, generate an application specific password, or implement OAuth, this is exactly the situation it's meant for.  I'm not sure the built in PHP libraries support it though.